# How to run a task if some other task has failed in Azure Devops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, task

I want to run a task B only if one particular task A is failed. How to achieve this is Azure DevOps. I tried this PowerShell but didn't work.

```
param(
    [string]$token = $(System.AccessToken),
        [string]$targetTaskName = "Signing and Time stamping",
        [string]$collectionURL = $(Build.Repository.Uri),
        [string]$projectName = $(System.TeamProject),
        [string]$buildId = $(Build.BuildId)
    )
echo $token
echo $targetTaskName 
echo $collectionURL
echo $projectName 
echo $buildId

    $buildTimelineREST="$collectionURL$projectName/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/Timeline?api-version=4.1"
    $base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "test",$token)))
    $result= Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $buildTimelineREST -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}
    $targetTask=$result.records | where { $_.Name -eq $targetTaskName }
    Write-Host $targetTask.result
    if($targetTask.result -eq "failed"){
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=task.signing.status]failure"
    }
```

[image]

When I put quotes in arguments I get this error.

```
param(
    [string]$token = "$(System.AccessToken)",
        [string]$targetTaskName = "Signing and Time stamping",
        [string]$collectionURL = "$(Build.Repository.Uri)",
        [string]$projectName = "$(System.TeamProject)",
        [string]$buildId = "$(Build.BuildId)"
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here has some points you should pay attention to:

- To get **collection URL**, you need use the variable
  `System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri`.
- You can use `env:xxxx` to call our Azure devops predefined
  variables if you would like to call these predefined variables directly in `ps1` file.
- Please don't convert `$(System.AccessToken)` to a **Base64** string.
  This `Base64` conversion is just available for PAT.
- Unless necessary, do not use **dots** in variable names. Because for
  Azure devops, we will treat it as [hierarchical](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#json-variable-substitution-notes) of the JSON file. So here you'd better use another variable name that do not has any special characters in it. As example, the name I specified is **SigningStatus**.

I made some changes and re-constructed your powershell script. Now everything goes as expected. Refer to below script:

```
[String]$projectName = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT
[String]$collectionURL= $env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI
[String]$targetTaskName = "Command Line Script"
[String]$buildId = $env:BUILD_BUILDID
Write-Host $targetTaskName 
Write-Host $collectionURL
Write-Host $projectName 
Write-Host $buildId
$buildTimelineREST="$collectionURL$projectName/_apis/build/builds/$buildId/Timeline?api-version=4.1"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $buildTimelineREST -Headers @{   
Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
}
$targetTask=$result.records | where { $_.Name -eq $targetTaskName }
Write-Host $targetTask.result
if($targetTask.result -eq "failed"){
Write-Host "ohhhh, it  failed"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SigningStatus]failure"
}
```

At last, please do not forget to enable the checkbox of **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token** at Agent job level.

[image]