# Run a task B when all the previous tasks have succeeded except few tasks(Run a task if a list of task is succeeded)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, powershell-2.0

I want to run a task B when all the previous tasks have succeeded except one. To be clear, task A comes before task B. The output of task A should not matter to task B and it should run if all the tasks other than A have passed. How to set a custom condition for that?

Or in other words, Run a task if a list of task is succeeded?

Comment: Consider using PowerShell jobs, and or workflows.

Comment: @Mehul-Parmar wich kind of task do you want to run and check? Powershell Cmdlets or exe-Files ... ?

Comment: @LosFla So the list of previous tasks I am talking about is a mix of Nuget Restore, Visual Studio Build, Powershell and batch commands. But I think that should not matter, right? All I want to know is how to write a custom condition to check if these specific tasks passed before.

Comment: @MehulParmar you can use $? after each command to check if it was successful or not. It retruns true or false. Or you can use try, catch for errorhandling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap and run your Task A under powershell or some other script. Make your script for TaskA such a way so it should not fail! You can have a condition under script for which if it fails to set the pipeline variable for further inspection but for pipeline task it should always pass.
Based on the pipeline variable you can run or cancel the upcoming tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Let's guessing the structure of your pipeline.

```
job:
  -Task A
  -Task B
  -Task C
  -Task NoRelated
  -Task D
```

Now, what you are looking for is `Task D` will run until `Task A` & `Task B` & `Task C` are all succeeded, and the result of `Task NoRelated` will not matters on `Task D`, right?

I think you should knew that as of now, there's no direct expression can let you achieve this. We have to consider to use work around. Just need add one additional task and configure the `condition` settings of tasks.

---

To counter your requirement, you can try with below suggestion.

- **Step1.**

Firstly, please ensure the **condition** setting of `Task A` & `Task B` & `Task C` are all **Only when all previous tasks have succeeded**:

[image]

At this moment, the `Task C` will run until `Task A` & `Task B` are **all succeeded**. If any task in `Task A` and `Task B` fails, `Task C` will be in the cancel state.

So, we just need to know the status of `Task C` to confirm whether `Task A` & `Task B` & `Task C` are all succeeded.

- **Step2:**

Add one powershell task into current agent job, and make sure this powershell task is executed after `Task A` & `Task B` & `Task C`. Then using the sample script of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956524/how-to-run-a-task-if-some-other-task-has-failed-in-azure-devops/63987283#63987283) to check the status of `Task C`. Let me name this powershell task as **Signing Status**.

Since we need to retrieve the status of Task C even `Task C` is failed, please set the condition of **Signing Status** task is **Even if a previous task has failed, even if the build was canceled**.

- **Step3:**

Set the condition of `Task D` is `eq(variables['SigningStatus'], 'succeeded')`.

[image]

---

**Overview of pipeline structure**：

```
                          condition setting

job:
  -Task A              --"Only when all previous tasks have succeeded"
  -Task B              --"Only when all previous tasks have succeeded"
  -Task C              --"Only when all previous tasks have succeeded"
  -Task NoRelated      --"Depend on yourself"
  -Task Signing Status --"Even if a previous task has failed, even if the build was canceled"
  -Task D              --"eq(variables['SigningStatus'], 'succeeded')"
```

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thank you! But what after Task D? If there is E, F, G, H they all should run only if previous tasks are succeeded except `Task NoRelated`. How to maintain that chain? I guess after each step I need to put a PowerShell script and update `SigningStatus` variable.

Comment: @MehulParmar, Nope, don't need that. That is too ugly. Just expand your powershell script logic to check these tasks' status.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $? after each command to check if it was successful or not. It retruns true or false. Or you can use try, catch for errorhandling.

```
If($?)
{
    # execute if last command returned true
}
else
{
    # execute if last command returned false
}
```

Or

```
Try 
{
    # command with parameter -ErrorAction Stop
    # to catch error in catch block

    # command to execute if successful
}
Catch
{
    # catch error with $_
    # or start another command 
}
```

Comment: oh you mean after each task I will have to write a Powershell script to check. I was more thinking of a `custom condition` in settings provided by pipeline.

Comment: Ah sorry, you mean something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Yeah because having a PowerShell between every task would not be feasible. I  was more in terms that after each task success if we can update a pipeline variable(through output variable or something like) to true and for each downstream task we can set a condition to run only if this value is `true`.